# Drop function in python not removing multiple fields

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, drop

So my code is

```
train_filtered = train_copy.drop(train_copy[train_copy['class'] == 'o' ].index)
train_filtered = train_copy.drop(train_copy[train_copy['class'] == 'h' ].index)
train_filtered['class'].value_counts()
```

there are 4 different class types s,d,h,o, and I am trying to add only s and d to a new df but when I run the third line it shows that I still have s,d, and o in the df if I reverse the order then I have s,d,h. Can multiple drops not be done in Python?

Comment: In the second line you're dropping from train_copy, not train_filtered, so the first line doesn't matter, as the second line just overwrites its result.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using `train_copy` on your second `train_filtered` call. The first call gets rid of `class o`, but is overwritten on the second call because you are using `train_copy` instead of `train_filtered`. You can fix the issue like this:

```
train_filtered = train_copy.drop(train_copy[train_copy['class'] == 'o' ].index)
train_filtered = train_filtered.drop(train_filtered[train_filtered['class'] == 'h' ].index)
train_filtered['class'].value_counts()
```

Alternatively, you can remove **both** classes in one `drop` call:

```
train_filtered = train_copy.drop(train_copy[(train_copy['class'] == 'o') | (train_copy['class'] == 'h')].index)
train_filtered['class'].value_counts()
```

Comment: In the alternative solution, I think you'd need `|` instead of `&` (i.e. or instead of and).